# Go through with renaming “offensive” to “rude/abusive”

Tags: bug, status-completed, wording, offensive

About a year ago the *offensive* flag was subject to some renaming, which finally settled down on *rude or abusive.* This has the advantage of capturing non-offensive abuses of the site and thus clearly applies to some forms of trolling to which *offensive* did not clearly apply.

However, in several parts of the interface (probably everywhere except in the flag dialogue), these flags are still called *offensive:*

[image: User flag history]

[image: Post view]

[image: Post flag history]

This leads to unnecessary confusion¹ and counteracts the new terminology being established. In particular some moderators almost only see those parts of the interface where *offensive* is still used and thus did not even notice the change.

---

<sup>¹ “Why did you flag that as offensive? It’s not offensive.” – “But it’s abusive.” – “Yes but the flag is called *offensive.*” – “No, it isn’t.” – …</sup>

Comment: synonym suggested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've gone through the codebase and updated a bunch of places that had "offensive" to "rude or abusive" (or similar - I did what made sense according to context).

This has been deployed already.

Please let me know if you find any that I've missed.